# How to get TextField value from HTML file to TypeScript file?

Tags: html, angular2-nativescript

I am new to nativescript. I want to store user data in my mobile. For that i have used Couchbase database. Now my requirement is to get TextField value when I clicked save button. `

```
<TextField hint=" firstName " [text]="_fname ">

</TextField>
<TextField hint="lastname " [text]="_lname ">

</TextField>

<button (tap)="save()" class="btn btn-primary active" text="Save"></button>
```

`

In above i need to get both the TextField values on button click.
Please do explain how to access the current value from textfield. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to solve this would be through two-way data binding. The first thing that you need to do is add `NativeScriptFormsModule` to the `NgModule` list of imports as follows.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then you'd need to update your component `.html` file to use two-way data binding. This binds the specified element to a property that you have on your component's .ts file.

```
<TextField hint=" firstName " [(ngModel)]="_fname "> </TextField>
<TextField hint="lastname " [(ngModel)]="_lname "> </TextField>

<button (tap)="save()" class="btn btn-primary active" text="Save"></button>
```

Then finally, ensure that you have `_fname` and `_lname` properties in the form's `.ts` file.

```
export class SomeComponent {
    _fname = "";
    _lname = "";

    save() {
        console.log(this._fname);
        console.log(this._lname);
        // Send values to your DB
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly I found my issue. I forgot to add in **app.module.ts**. Now it's working. Nobody explain about that we have to make changes in app.modules.ts. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I forgot this line to add in **app.module.ts** import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";